# Almacenar una sub-lista de objetos

Tags: java

Tengo un duda por cómo realizar una partición de un List de objetos.Lo que quiero es que tengo un List con 1000 objetos y quiero realizar un sublist para tener 500 objetos por un lado y otros 500 por otro.

Tengo una clase objeto llamada pedidos y he creado un ArrayList de pedidos con 1000 objetos de pedidos.

Lo que quiero conseguir es meter esos dos List en un arrayList nuevo para luego poder pasarlo por parámetro.Necesito que sea así ya que al llamar al método no se puede luego trabajar .(podría enviar mi ArrayList de pedidos y coger lo que yo necesitaría pero el método necesita que sea List).

Es lo que se me ha ocurrido para poder trabajar por separado los datos pero si hubiera otra opción que ahora mismo no caigo podría aplicarla para solo mandar una parte y luego la otra al método.

// la unica forma de particionar para luego pasar los dos List de objetos seria asi, pero no se como puedo meterlo en un List para luego ser llamados o si hay otra forma.

```
List<pedidos> pedido1 = pedidos.subList(0, 500); 
List<pedidos> pedido1 = pedidos.subList(500, 100);
```

Comment: Comparte el código de lo que has desarrollado para poder guiarte. Saludos.

Comment: Sí, y dale algo de formato al texto :(

Comment: puedes colocar la firma del método donde que debes llamar y el código donde declaras los ArrayList de pedidos??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta 1

Suponiendo que lo que quieres hacer es coger un `List`de 1000 objetos y partirlo en 2 `List`(de 500 cada uno) para luego volver a juntarlos, simplemente tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
List<pedidos> listanueva;
listanueva.addAll(pedidos1);
listanueva.addAll(pedidos2);
```

## Respuesta 2

Si lo que quieres es crear un `List`de las 2 listas que has creado (`pedidos1`y `pedidos2`) entonces simplemente crea un `List<List<pedidos>>`:

```
List<pedidos> pedidos1 = pedidos.subList(0, 500); 
List<pedidos> pedidos2 = pedidos.subList(500, 1000);
List<List<pedidos>> listaPedidos = new List<List<pedidos>>();
listaPedidos.add(pedidos1);
listaPedidos.add(pedidos2);
```

Espero haber resuelto tu duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta es lo que estaba buscando. Queria recoger los datos y enviarlos dentro de un List pero tenia un lio en como enviar la informacion. Gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres tratar las listas por separado, el método [`sublist(int indiceInicial, int indiceFinal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) devuelve una nueva `List` , pero esa Lista está respaldada por la Lista original.

Esto quiere decir que **las operaciones no estructurales (no reordenación) en esas sub Listas afectan a la Lista original**.

#### Ejemplo

```
List<Integer> listaPrincipal = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    listaPrincipal.add(i);
}

listaPrincipal.forEach(System.out::println);

List<Integer> subLista2= listaPrincipal.subList(5, 10);
List<Integer> subLista1= listaPrincipal.subList(0, 5);

subLista1.replaceAll(i -> i += 10);
subLista2.replaceAll(i -> i += 100);

listaPrincipal.forEach(System.out::println);
```

#### Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
105
106
107
108
109
```

> Si quieres crear otra lista que tenga exactamente el los mismos objetos y de la cual no te importe el orden, utiliza la Lista original.

Answer (score 1):

### Codigo

```
package javaapplication8;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Object> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        /* Llenamos la lista */
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            lista.add(i);
        }

        List<Object> primeraLista = lista.subList(0, 500);
        List<Object> segundaLista = lista.subList(500, lista.size());

        System.out.println("La primera lista tiene " + primeraLista.size() + " elementos.");
        System.out.println("La segunda lista tiene " + segundaLista.size() + " elementos.");

    }

}
```

---

#### Resultado

```
La primera lista tiene 500 elementos.
La segunda lista tiene 500 elementos.
```

---

### Explicacion

De acuerdo a lo que podemos encontrar sobre la funcion `subList()`, **esta no trabaja como lo hace un `substring()`**, es decir, tu le debes indicar un **rango valido**, para que ella pueda hacer el "corte" de la lista.

Por lo tanto, cuando ejecutamos esta linea:

```
List<pedidos> pedido1 = pedidos.subList(0, 500);
```

Le indicamos al compilador algo como:

> Devuelve la lista de elementos desde el indice 0 al indice 500.

---

Pero cuando ejecutamos esta:

```
List<pedidos> pedido1 = pedidos.subList(500, 100);
```

Le indicariamos algo como:

> Devuelve la lista de elementos desde el indice 500 al 100 ???

Por lo cual podemos obtener este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(500) > toIndex(100)

---

**Por lo tanto, al final solo hemos dejado esta linea en su lugar**:

```
List<pedidos> pedido2 = pedidos.subList(500, pedidos.size());
```

Debido a que `pedidos.size()` en nuestro caso nos devuelve el numero `1000`, para lo cual le indicamos al compilador algo como:

> Devuelve la lista de elementos desde el indice 500 al indice 1000.

Lo cual **no nos genera un error**.

---

#### [Ejemplo en linea!](https://tio.run/##dVA7b8IwEJ6TX3HKZB4N6dAJitQ9VQfGqoMh1@hSx47sCxWt@O2pA4YmQtxi@7v7HudK7uWDaVBXxVfXUd0Yy1B5MG2ZVPpirTzk5HgZ3/TOcNy0W0U72CnpHLxK0vAbx1FAHUv2x95QAbXviQ1b0uX7B0hbuslpNOqFVm/bCne8BuUfEp5B4zdc3VdrMfFWECpaTCFXqGVtHCgZONPF/8CnsSBIM5CXypb@WMFjlvW32ay3hUFF0UkglUUhyPtc8ePAchSysVSjlXnIeqa7dtsDIpvDU5YNdUZch2WriztcT5xfIPpBMRmtvTk4xjo1Lac@gWalRZLLS5rwDUyoERKYjVIGOY8mgApr1GxcmgxT3lEPeW/Uh3vcV@//8Nh1fw)